# If the sample space is an Euclidean Space, we can use a different type of PDF

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, definitions

Reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476568/strange-definitions-about-basic-probability-need-clarification/1580395#comment3335933_1580395) post, I realize that is possible to have *another* type of PDF (probability density function) in the special case when the sample space is an Euclidean space.

Usually, we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, a random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ and the PDF of $X$, $f_X:\mathbb{R}\to[0, \infty)$. The whole point of the PDF is that we can integrate it over any borel set $A$ (contained in the codomain of $X$) and get the probability $ P[X\in A] = \int_A f_X\ dx$.

What about the case when we have that $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is the Borel sigma algebra over $\mathbb{R}$? Looks like it's easier to define the PDF to be a function $f:\Omega\to[0,\infty)$ such that $P[A] = \int_A f\ dx$. So we still can use this PDF to get the probability of events via integration over borel sets. The idea in the book (mentioned on the other post) is that $\Omega$ can be a manifold, so we integrate the PDF over a subset contained in this manifold to get the probability of that subset. If $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is a random variable (not necessarily the map $x\to x$), we could talk about $f_X$, the PDF of $X$, such as described before. But in this sample space, we can use the *other* PDF $f$. So, instead calculating $\int_Af_X\ dx = P[X\in A]$, we can calculate $\int_{\{X\in A\}}f\ dx = P[X\in A]$. Note that the first integral is over the codomain of $X$, but the second is over the sample space $\Omega$.

[This](http://www.ams.org/notices/200511/what-is.pdf) article in particular is an example of what I'm saying. Instead defining real random variables $X_{ij}$ as the entries of a random matrix, it's possible to see the sample space as $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and **define** a probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ to work with.

I want to know if there is some technical detail I should be aware of and how common is this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula 
$$\int_{\{X\in A\}}f\ dx = P[X\in A]\tag{1}$$
(I guess you wanted to say it should hold for all Borel $A\subseteq\mathbb R$) can be rewritten as $\int_B f\ dx = P(B)$ for all $B$ in $\sigma(X)$, the smallest sigma-algebra with respect to which the random variable (r.v.) $X$ is measurable. So, condition $(1)$ means precisely that $f$ is the density (that is, the Radon--Nikodym derivative) 
of the restriction $P|_{\sigma(X)}$ of the measure $P$ to $\sigma(X)$ with respect to the restriction $\lambda|_{\sigma(X)}$ of the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ to $\sigma(X)$:
$$f=\frac{dP|_{\sigma(X)}}{d\lambda|_{\sigma(X)}}. \tag{2}
$$
Such a density (when it exists) depends on $X$ only through $\sigma(X)$ and thus usually provides little information on the r.v. $X$, and it provides no information on its distribution. 
To illustrate this point, suppose that $(2)$ holds for a r.v. $X$ and some "alternative pdf" $f$. Let $Y_1:=1-X$, $Y_2:=X^3$, and $Y_3:=\arctan X$. Then $\sigma(Y_1)=\sigma(Y_2)=\sigma(Y_3)=\sigma(X)$ and hence the same "alternative pdf" $f$ will serve all these r.v.'s: $X,Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$.

Somewhat more generally, suppose in addition that the distribution function (d.f.) $F$ of $X$ is continuous and strictly increasing (c.s.i.). Let $G$ be any other c.s.i. d.f. Let $Y:=G^{-1}(F(X))$. Then the d.f. of the r.v. $Y$ is $G$. On the other hand, $Y$ is a c.s.i. transformation of $X$ and hence $\sigma(Y)=\sigma(X)$. So, $Y$ is served by the same "alternative pdf" $f$ as $X$, even though the d.f. $Y$ is an arbitrary c.s.i. d.f. $G$.

Therefore, I don't see why such a "alternative pdf" would be of use.

As for the linked note by Diaconis, it seems to have nothing to do with formula $(1)$, even though he does let $\Omega=\mathbb R^{n^2}$ (nothing wrong or unusual with that). What Diaconis does in that note to answer the question in its title "What is a Random Matrix?" is just provide a particular construction, via Gram--Schmidt orthogonalization, of the Haar measure on the orthogonal group $O_n$, starting with the standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb R^{n^2}$, which latter is the product of $n^2$ copies of the standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Diaconis considered $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ as the sample space with the Haar measure $\mu$, if I understand correctly. For instance, if exists a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n^2}\to[0,\infty)$  such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n^2}}f\ dx = 1$ and $\int_A f\ dx = \mu(A)$ (for all borel sets $A$), could I call that function a PDF? The PDF I'm contemplating goes in this lines.

Comment: No, as I said, Diaconis considered (as a starting point) the standard Gaussian (not Haar) measure on $\mathbb R^{n^2}$. Also, the Haar measure is defined on the sigma-algebra of Borel subsets of the compact group $O_n$, rather than of $\mathbb R^{n^2}$. Further, I suggest that such imprecise phrases as "the sample space with ... a measure" be avoided. Why do you need a "sample space" if you can have a set?

Comment: I have added details on why the "alternative pdf" provides no information on the distribution of $X$.

Comment: If by $\int_A f\, dx$ you mean the integral with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ (say), then the condition that $\int_A f\, dx=\mu(A)$ for all Borel sets $A\subseteq\mathbb R^{n^2}$ means, by definition, that $f$ is the density of the measure $\mu$ with respect to $\lambda$. Of course, then one can construct any number of r.v.'s $X$ with values in $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ such that $f$ is the pdf of $X$, in the conventional sense. One such construction is letting $X$ be the identity mapping of $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ endowed with the Borel measure $\mu$. However, I don't see anything new here.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. My confusion started reading the post I mentioned first. This one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476568/strange-definitions-about-basic-probability-need-clarification/1580395#comment3335933_1580395

Comment: The author made a little mistake and should've write $\mu(A) = \int_Af\ dx$ (he doesn't write the $dx$ but this is the measure used, there is a image in a comment of mine there). The data space doesn't come from any random variable, it works as a sample space. It means their definition of *(probability) density* is as mine (if I didn't make a mistake), and then starts my confusion because it looks like they really define the PDF over the sample space (instead related to random variables).

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, but I would be very glad if you enlighten me about my comment above. I feel I almost understand everything, almost. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: In that comment above, you seem mainly concerned about notation and terminology. The term pdf is used to refer to the density of the distribution of a r.v. w.r. to the Lebesgue measure; see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function . Also, it's better to have as few notions as possible, and make sure they are defined and/or anyway clearly understood by your audience. I have already advised you against using the vague term "sample space". You are still using it, and now also "data space", the meaning of which latter I can hardly be sure about.

Comment: I'm using the term "sample space" as people use in probability usually. It's a set (plus a sigma-algebra) of the outcomes we are interested. I don't know what is the problem. About the term "data space", I borrowed it from the link in my comment above, and I did this precisely so you could be able to understand the meaning before making your comment.

Comment: A better, quite unabiguous term is a measurable space, instead of a sample space. Also, I now see that the term "data space" is indeed used at the link you provided. However, it is not defined there either, and even caused some confusion there as well. I also think it is generally not a good idea to bring questions from math.stackexchage to mathoverflow.

Comment: Ok, I won't bring more questions from ME, didn't know about that. About data space, it's defined here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dnx1itp96ky1suz/a.png?dl=0
Did I understand things wrongly or the author really defined a PDF like I was introducing here?
One more time, thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: The excerpt from book at your link says it introduces the term "data space" because of "lacking some established name". I have never seen such a definition anywhere else. Your definition of an alternative pdf by formula $(1)$ does seem similar to the definition of the probability density in the book, except that there the sigma-algebra does not seem to be specified (or linked to a r.v.), whereas you seem to specify the sigma-algebra to be $\sigma(X)$. The book is not reviewed on MathSciNet. Even looking at the excerpt you posted, I don't think it should be taken as a mathematical book.

Comment: This is a link to the book: http://www.springer.com/br/book/9783642388958
I'm about to take a one semester course on this book and I'm really concerned that this definitions are not well accepted.